# How to get programmatic access to controls of Windows CE app running in Emulator using Coded UI or MSAA?

Tags: c#, automated-tests, windows-ce

I am trying to automate the application developed in Windows CE. I have created a simple Form consisting of Button and TextBox.
I run the application with the **Pocket PC 2003 Emulator** and once i record the test, it is able to automate the process like it can click the Button and using the keyboard on the simulator, it can also type in the textBox.

Now my concern is to validate the things like i want to get the TextBox as a control in my client application and want to validate the text inside it.

With CodedUI, I am unable to "***Add Assertions"*** because the focus does not go inside the Emulator like below
[image]

Now, the window of the Emulator shows its been developed in the MSAA technology, i want to add verification points in my test and in order to do that i need to have programmatic access of the controls in the Emulator.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

The emulator is a virtual machine, meaning that to your PC it's a completely separate machine.  The host PC doesn't have access to the windows or controls of the hosted machine in any way.  You could probably script some sort of location based output to simulate clicks onto the VM, but there's no way you can get a windows handle and do things like put text into or read text out of a control.  Your better off creating a test proxy that runs on a device (could be the emulator or a physical device) and communicate with that proxy via network, RAPI, remote tools framework or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks for providing useful information. Now i will try to deploy the application using ActiceSync and then will run the app in device and then will take the remote of the device in my PC and will try to automate that. Does it sound good to you?